# Python: I can't parse a csv from stdin in function

Tags: python, macos, csv, argparse

## Can't parse csv from stdin in function

Hello, I'm on my Mac trying to use Pythons's `csv` module to parse a space separated file passed via stdin:

```
printf "2020-01-01 Ben 2\n2020-02-01 Jenny 4\n" | ./tmp.py
```

When I run the code with the `working` function called at then end, I get the expected result:

```
$ printf "2020-01-01 Ben 2\n2020-02-01 Jenny 4\n" | ./tmp.py
function: working
['2020-01-01', 'Ben', '2']
['2020-02-01', 'Jenny', '4']
```

When I run it with the `not_working` function called at the end I get an error:

```
$ printf "2020-01-01 Ben 2\n2020-02-01 Jenny 4\n" | ./tmp.py
function: not_working
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tmp.py", line 36, in <module>
    not_working() # if working() was here, it would work
  File "./tmp.py", line 27, in not_working
    print_csv(args.infile, delimiter=' ')
  File "./tmp.py", line 20, in print_csv
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter)
_csv.Error: unknown dialect
```

Here is the minimal example with `not_working` called at the end

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import csv
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "infile",
    nargs="?",
    type=argparse.FileType("r"),
    default=sys.stdin,
)
args = parser.parse_args()

def print_csv(infile, delimiter):
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

def not_working():
    print("function: not_working")
    with args.infile:
        print_csv(args.infile, delimiter=' ')

def working():
    print("function: working")
    with args.infile:
        reader = csv.reader(args.infile, delimiter=" ")
        for row in reader:
            print(row)

not_working() # if working() was here, it would work
# working()
```

Why is this breaking? Why can I parse a CSV outside of a function, but not inside of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass `delimiter` as a keyword argument in `print_csv`; that meant you were effectively calling `csv.reader(infile, dialect=delimiter)`, and ' ' is an unknown dialect (typically, this is restricted to `'excel'`, `'excel-tab'`, or `'unix'`.

Please refer to the documentation on [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) method signature for further details.